# Angularfire Document Referance collection

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

```
    return this.orderCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions =>
        actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Order;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

[image]

Now How can I get Document referance Data in angularfire2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to load the referenced document separately. So something like:

```
customerRef = a.payload.doc.get("customerId");
customerRef.get().then((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data());
})
```

Comment: I found this this customer referance data But How to return it with {id, ...data}. Please mention kindly

Comment: Assuming you're asking about the asynchronous nature of `get().then()`, have a look at these links that discuss client-side joins with AngularFire: https://stackoverflow.com//50346296/, https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-joins-similar-to-sql/, https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2061 (all from https://www.google.com/search?q=angularfire+firestore+join).

Comment: yes thats So much halpfull but I need to return  like this `{ id, ...data, referance_data}` . in this case how can i do that ?